# Push to GitHub from XCode 5.1 Without Using Terminal

Tags: xcode, git

If I have a local repository on my mac desktop, how can I push it to GitHub directly from XCode 5.1 without using the terminal? I know you can do it with this:

```
cd <directory of xcode>
git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR-REPOS-NAME
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a remote.

> Source Control > Select your project > Configure...

Then hit the `+`, and you'll be able to add your remote.

After this you'll then be able to go to (after you have performed a commit)

> Source Control > Push...

All features can be accessed from this menu, or by right-clicking files in the project navigator

Comment: Hooray for 2k! You're part of the club now :P

Answer (score 1):

Use the Xcode 'Source Control' menu drop down.  Here you can "checkout" and then later "push" source code to a git repository, such as one hosted on GitHub.